# spring singleton object state

Tags: java, spring

Here I have one doubt with **spring singleton object**.

> Spring will create atleast one object per bean definition depending on the scope.
>   for singleton scope, you will get only one object per bean definiton.

As spring context provide us singleton instance then why I am not able to share same session of it.

The below code give error:

> Throw null pointer error.
>   org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started

**while trying to access same instance session. even session instance is null.**

In  main method

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  TestDao dao =  (TestDao) ApplicationContext.getInstance().getBean(DaoType.TestDao.toString());
  dao.startOperation();
  for(Test test:testList)
  {
     saveIsBean(test,true)
  }
  dao.endOperation();
}
```

This method save data if session open then reuse it.

```
private void saveIsBean(IsBean isBean,boolean isSessionAlreadyOpen) throws NTException
 {
 TestDao dao =  (TestDao) ApplicationContext.getInstance().getBean(DaoType.TestDao.toString());
  if(isSessionAlreadyOpen)
 {
 //dao.startOperation(); If I start session again then it works.
 dao.getSession().saveOrUpdate(isBean); //Throw null pointer error. org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
  }
 else
 {
 dao.saveOrUpdate(isBean);
  }
 } 
public void startOperation() throws HibernateException {
 session = HibernateFactory.openSession();
 transaction = session.beginTransaction();
 }
```

If I start session again  or pass same session instance in method then it works fine but I do not understand why it does not work. **singleton instance does not have same state in spring context!!**

Thanks In Advance

Comment: The spring application context is never bootstrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Spring you must bootstrap the depenedency injection container.  The container can point to an xml file defining your beans or a class using Springs Java configuration.  Once the container is bootstrapped it manages all of your beans as singletons.  The code you provided uses a static method on the `ApplicationContext` class so it never has an actual handle to an instance of the `ApplicationContext` meaning no beans are defined within it.

Here is an example of bootstrapping via xml:

```
// create and configure beans
ApplicationContext context =
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"services.xml", "daos.xml"});
```

Comment: I did bootstrap for  applicationContext.xml file in application context. like 
`_springContext = new GenericApplicationContext();
  XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(_springContext);
  xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("resources/applicationContext.xml"));
  _springContext.refresh();`
and The file has import of `Test.xml` file. is it not bootstrap in real term?

Comment: @BMT that bootstrap code needs to be in the main method.  Did you simply omit it?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your config.

From spring docs
The scope of the Spring singleton is best described as per container and per bean.

The issue you are having could just be a configuration thing.
By default, a bean will be a singleton, unless the bean has a parent bean definition in which case it will inherit the parent's scope.
  [1]: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: @KevinBowersox Thanks there is mistake in mapping. I did not see that there is scope defined as `prototype`..so obviously that give new instance of it.